# Why can't I install the Windows Phone 8.1 emulators?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have visual studio 2013 with update 2 installed.. below is the error I get and my system details..
[image: this is the error I get when installing emulators]

[image: and this is my system]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go in your motherboard's BIOS and enable Hyper-V or its equivalent

Comment: Assuming, of course, that your motherboard and CPU support VT-x, AMD-V, or VT-i

Comment: cant it be done from Control Panel>>Programs>> Turn Windows Features On and Off .. It is enabled already from there ?

Comment: This is a BIOS feature, nothing to do with the operating system.

Comment: 2630QM does support [VT-x](http://ark.intel.com/products/52219/Intel-Core-i7-2630QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz)

Comment: Thankyou for your support guys ..

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V requires [Windows 8.1 Professional edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx). You may need to upgrade.
If you already have the Professional edition, then verify you have [Data Execution Prevention (DEP)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731898.aspx) enabled in your BIOS.

Comment: Note DEP can't be turned off in x64 versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 8.1 Pro or better x64 (64-bit) and you are still getting this failure, then most likely your CPU is missing support for SLAT.

See [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1401.hyper-v-list-of-slat-capable-cpus-for-hosts.aspx) article for details.